# Cannot extend virtual disk with `cfdisk`: Failed to resize partition

Tags: debian, lvm, proxmox

I'd like to extend my virtual disk in a Proxmox environment from 64GB to 100GB. The guest OS is Debian 10. I've extended the virtual disk in Proxmox (it now has 100GB) and restarted the guest OS.

`cfdisk` correctly sees that the size of the disk is now 100GiB:

```
                                             Disk: /dev/vda
                          Size: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
                                   Label: dos, identifier: 0x9f2b12a1

    Device           Boot               Start           End       Sectors      Size     Id Type
>>  /dev/vda1        *                   2048        499711        497664      243M     83 Linux
    /dev/vda2                          501758     134215679     133713922     63.8G      5 Extended
    └─/dev/vda5                        501760     134215679     133713920     63.8G     8e Linux LVM
    Free space                      134215680     209715199      75499520       36G
```

However I'm unable to extend either `vda2` or `vda5` with the following error messages:

- /dev/vda2:  Maximum size is 68461528064 bytes
- /dev/vda5:  Failed to resize partition #5.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: exact same problem - Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by creating a new partition via `cfdisk` and then created a new physical volume via `pvcreate /dev/sda3`. I added this new pv to the my volume group: `vgextend /dev/VMTEMPLATE-vg /dev/sda3`.

The VG should now be the correspondingly enlarged.
Then I resized the logical volume: `lvresize /dev/VMTEMPLATE-vg/root /dev/sda3`.

Finally I adjusted the size of the filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/mapper/VMTEMPLATE--vg-root`.

Answer (score 0):

In VMWare

Edit VM guest and add some disk space to the first disk and save.

Run cfdisk to utilize the free space

```
$ sudo cfdisk
```

Create a new partition from the free space.  In my case it was /dev/sda3

Create new physical volume

```
$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3
```

Physical volume "/dev/sda3" successfully created.

Add the new physical volume to my volume group

```
$ sudo vgextend /dev/transfer-vg /dev/sda3
```

Volume group "transfer-vg" successfully extended

Resize logical volume

```
$ sudo lvresize /dev/transfer-vg/root /dev/sda3
```

Size of logical volume transfer-vg/root changed from <5.52 GiB (1413 extents) to <17.52 GiB (4485 extents).
Logical volume transfer-vg/root successfully resized.

Find the name of filesystem to be resized

```
$ df -hT | grep mapper
```

/dev/mapper/transfer--vg-root ext4      5.4G  4.2G  911M  83% /

/dev/mapper/transfer-data     ext4       79G   14G   61G  19% /var/www/data

resize filesystem

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/transfer--vg-root
```

resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/transfer--vg-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/transfer--vg-root is now 4592640 (4k) blocks long.

Answer (score 0):

`cfdisk` may not let you resize the partition because it contains other partitions in use. Instead you can use a tool that can do things at low level: `parted`

Warning: Take a VM snapshot in advance as you could lose data if you do things wrong. There's no write, save or undo.

In `parted` console type `resizepart <PART_NUMBER> <NEW_END_POSITION>`

Notice that you set the end position of the partition and not the size. For example, in the sample below, the extended partition 2 is resized to use the remaining free space at the end of the disk.

```
(parted) print free                                                       
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  300MB   299MB   primary   ext2         boot
        300MB   301MB   1048kB            Free Space
 2      301MB   12.9GB  12.6GB  extended
 5      301MB   12.9GB  12.6GB  logical                lvm
        12.9GB  21.5GB  8591MB            Free Space

(parted) resizepart 2 21.5GB                                              

(parted) print free                                                       
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  300MB   299MB   primary   ext2         boot
        300MB   301MB   1048kB            Free Space
 2      301MB   21.5GB  21.2GB  extended
 5      301MB   12.9GB  12.6GB  logical                lvm
        12.9GB  21.5GB  8591MB            Free Space
```

As you can see, the end of partition 2 matches the end of free space. After this, you can go to the friendly `cfdisk` to create the new logical partition.